# Webform field default value + Profile field value

Tags: 8, users, webforms

I have a simple **Webform** (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform):

1. Single field called "name".

I also have a **Profile** (https://www.drupal.org/project/profile):

1. Profile is called "basic_profile".
2. Profile contains 2 fields: "field_name" and "field_department".

I want the default value of my Webform field "name" to be the content of the user's Basic Profile value for "field_name", but I cannot save the form because "*Default value* is using the following invalid tokens".

I have also tried using "[webform-authenticated-user:display-name]" which does not work.

I have tried using "[current-user:display-name]" which works but does not give me the info I want.

So how can I get the user's profile values to be used as default values for form fields? Thanks!

P.S.: The reason for this is that we are authenticating via Active Directory, and Drupal will be loading a user's profile from AD upon login. Therefore we want to leverage all data that exists in AD.

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.2",
        "drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar": "^1.5",
        "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.3",
        "drupal/business": "^1.7",
        "drupal/business_responsive_theme": "^1.1",
        "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
        "drupal/core": "~8.5",
        "drupal/devel": "^1.2",
        "drupal/domain": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/domain_theme_switch": "^1.3",
        "drupal/eform": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^1.27",
        "drupal/insert": "^1.0",
        "drupal/maestro": "^2.1@RC",
        "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.1",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.4",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.2",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.1",
        "drupal/profile": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/token": "^1.3",
        "drupal/webform": "^5.0@RC",
        "drupal/workflow": "^1.0",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
        "kint-php/kint": "^2.2",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "~8.5"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "drupal-scaffold": "DrupalComposer\\DrupalScaffold\\Plugin::scaffold",
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "patches": {
            "drupal/domain": {
                "Drupal Domain New Content Type Domain Fields": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-03-15/2953168-da-form-display-13.patch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Make profile fields avalaible as tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile/issues/2785585), tokens for Profile fields was added, but it was added to **dev** 4 months ago. Since the 8.x-1.0-rc1 version was released 9 months ago, it does not have tokens.

So either switch to dev version until they release it or apply the patch provided on [#22](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile/issues/2785585#comment-12487576) to 8.x-1.0-rc1.